# Is this change in the order of integration correct?

Tags: integration

Assume we have an integral as follows

$$I= \int  \int f_X(x) g(x,y) \ dy \ dx$$

Can I do the following

$$I= \int f_X(x)  \int g(x,y) \ dy \ dx = \int f_X(x) u(x) \ dx$$

where $$\int g(x,y) \ dy= u(x)$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true so long as the [Fubini-Tonelli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#The_Fubini.E2.80.93Tonelli_theorem) applies.

Comment: In simpler terms (without measure theory) if both your integrals are absolutely convergent